# Trying to avoid AppDomains

Tags: c#, dll, plugins, mono, appdomain

I have a long running C# server application running on Linux/mono, and I have added the ability to load DLL assemblies on the fly to extend the application.  I have discovered updating those DLL assemblies at runtime cant be done without using AppDomains, which by the looks of will just get in the way of what I have already done.  Sure there will be workarounds, but that's not what I really want.

Does mono provide any alternative solutions that I might have missed? Does C# 4.0 have anything new in this area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Mono.CSharp library. You can compile c# code on the fly, and place hooks into your main application to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading in a new assembly to modify behavior, have you considered breaking up the application into distinct components, and communicating between them via a webservice or TCP/IP? That way you can change out the behavior of the application (at runtime) by changing where the components call. For example, you can build a new component with the new behavoir, webservice for example, and then instruct all the existing components to use it.

It'll also solve some memory issues with long running applications with the mono run-time.

Comment: All the message plumbing, and overheads that brings is what I am trying to avoid.  I have not had any problems with my app running for a long time with mono.